# My Nav Bar Font will not change too my custom font when I open the app for the first time

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

My Nav Bar Font will not change too my custom font when I open the app for the first time but when I go to another page and come back to the page the Font changes. Any idea on how to fix it where the Nav bar font is always the correct font?

**Default font below. This is right when I open the app.** 
[image]

[image]

My Custom Font Above when I clicked into a page and then came back to this page the Font updated.

This is my App Delegate code below. Any help would be great :)

```
    let navigationFont = UIFont(name: "MuseoSansRounded-900", size: 17)!
    let navigationLargeTitleFont = UIFont(name: "MuseoSansRounded-900", size: 34)!

    let navigationFontAttributes = [kCTFontAttributeName : navigationFont]
    let navigationLargeFontAttributes = [kCTFontAttributeName : navigationLargeTitleFont]

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = navigationFontAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = navigationLargeFontAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(navigationFontAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any], for: .normal)
```

**I have solved the problem. I moved the code higher up on the App Delegation and the font is now changing when I first come to the page. The updated code is below. Thank you to everyone for the help!**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // NAV BAR COLOR FOR ALL THE NAVS AND THE FONTS BELOW.

    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = blackSupportalColor

    // Navigation Bar Font Below
    let navigationFont = UIFont(name: "MuseoSansRounded-900", size: 17)!
    let navigationLargeTitleFont = UIFont(name: "MuseoSansRounded-900", size: 34)!

    let navigationFontAttributes = [kCTFontAttributeName : navigationFont]
    let navigationLargeFontAttributes = [kCTFontAttributeName : navigationLargeTitleFont]

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = navigationFontAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = navigationLargeFontAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(navigationFontAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any], for: .normal)
```

Comment: In which method in `AppDelegate` do you call this?

Comment: Thanks @agibson007 how can I set it directly as well?

Comment: @Tom its in -->     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

Comment: I think we need to see more of the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function. Where these are called in relation to other calls is important.

Comment: @picciano you were right! I moved the calls to the top of the page and it fixed the issue!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's commonly because you haven't included them in your Xcode project.

You can follow this link which will tell you how to add them: https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/how-to-import-fonts-into-xcode-swift-3-f0de7e921ef8

That guide is for **Swift 3** but the process is still the same for Xcode 9.

Comment: I have them in the Xcode project. If you look at the two images; One have the default font and the other has my custom font. The issue is when I open the app for the First time the page displays the Default font but when I leave the pass and Come back to that page the font updates to my custom font...

Comment: Does it still occur if you assigned the font programmatically on the first VC?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this also. The Font is working for my "Title", just not for the other things. But it works once I leave the page and come back to the page

Comment: Thank you for the help on this. I solved it by moving the code higher up on the app delegate page.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I moved the code higher up on the App Delegation and the font is now changing when I first come to the page. The updated code is below. Thank you to everyone for the help!

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // NAV BAR COLOR FOR ALL THE NAVS AND THE FONTS BELOW.

    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = blackSupportalColor

    // Navigation Bar Font Below
    let navigationFont = UIFont(name: "MuseoSansRounded-900", size: 17)!
    let navigationLargeTitleFont = UIFont(name: "MuseoSansRounded-900", size: 34)!

    let navigationFontAttributes = [kCTFontAttributeName : navigationFont]
    let navigationLargeFontAttributes = [kCTFontAttributeName : navigationLargeTitleFont]

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = navigationFontAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = navigationLargeFontAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(navigationFontAttributes as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any], for: .normal)
```